# safely remove java, .net, visual c++, MSXML

Tags: windows-7, java, .net-framework, visual-c++, msxml

I have java, .net, visual c++, MSXML preinstalled on my new windows 7 laptop. In the past I've found I don't use java or .NET for any essential applications and have uninstalled them.

is there a way I can find out which of my installed applications use any of  java, .net, visual c++, MSXML?

Alternatively is there anywhere I can find out what windows 7 applications require them, or can anyone suggest some popular applications that use them that I may have preinstalled/may want to install.

edit: part of the point of this post is to build up a list of popular applications dependent on the java etc... as there doesn't seem to be one anywhere else on the web :b

Comment: Why remove java / .net other than the fact you don't like it? Over time I'm sure you will come across an installer or web page that requires .net/java

Comment: every time it updates it tends to add about 100MB, sometimes a lot more. When I uninstalled all java updates on my last laptop I managed to save between 0.5 and 1 gig of disk space.

Comment: Disk space is cheap these days. Must be an OLD laptop.

Comment: Yep it's cheap, but if you have about 60gig of music, 40 gig of pictures, operating system (maybe 2 or 3 if you want to do testing of web sites across platforms) plus a number of web development and graphics packages installed a standard laptop hard drive of about 250GB quickly fills up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:  You could always try removing them, seeing what breaks, and searching for replacements as needed.  If no replacements found, reinstall pieces until it works again.

Commentary:  Personally, I'd say it's better to just keep them.  The disk space argument is weak since it's such a small percentage of your available space.

Answer (score 1):

the VC++ and msxml libraries are needed for IE.  Also, you are better off keeping .net, as Microsoft is migrating more and more of their software to it (and, hopefully, eventually *everything* will run on .net, allowing us to finally switch to a new processor architecture).